# Kernels correlation in Python

Tags: python, correlation, blobs

I need to calculate the correlation between kernels located in two matrices with different dimension. The matrices contain the same blob, with small changes in shape. Do you know if there is any alternative to `correlate2d`, now under [stsci_python](http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyraf/stsci_python), for calculating the correlation between the two kernels (blobs)? I tried using it but it's not clear which modules to use.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the exact functionality you are looking for but I would have check numpy
http://www.numpy.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`correlate2d` is now included in [agpy](https://code.google.com/p/agpy/), which can be installed via `pip install agpy`.

Comment: Another option is to use skimage, as done [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_template.html).